# How to find logs that contain certain string in lots of gz/regular files and save it as one/more txt files?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, text-processing

**New question on 22.9.2016, down below!**

My path looks like this:

```
~/Desktop/logs
├── first_folder
|   ├── 11.11 (folder)
│   |   ├── access_log
│   |   ├── access_log.1.gz
│   |   :
│   |   └── access_log.40.gz
|   └── 11.12 (folder)
│       ├── access_log
│       ├── access_log.1.gz
│       :
│       └── access_log.16.gz
├── second_folder (folder)
|   ├── 31.11 (folder)
│   |   ├── access_log
│   |   ├── access_log.1.gz
│   |   :
│   |   └── access_log.20.gz
|   └── 31.15 (folder)
│       ├── access_log
│       ├── access_log.1.gz
│       :
:       └── access_log.38.gz
└── last_folder
    ├── 91.11 (folder)
    |   ├── access_log
    |   ├── access_log.1.gz
    |   :
    |   └── access_log.25.gz
    └── 91.15 (folder)
        ├── access_log
        ├── access_log.1.gz
        :
        └── access_log.30.gz
```

From all the logs I have to extract the data that contain string: `/Jan/2016`

### Question #1

How can I get all the records from all the files in all folders and save it as `single_file.txt`

### **Edit #1**

Possible answer:

```
$ find . -name \*.* | xargs -0 zgrep -E '/Jan/2016' > single_file.txt
```

File is really really huge, lots of GB.

Output:

```
single_file.txt
./first_folder/11.11/access_log.9.gz: ... text ...
./first_folder/11.12/access_log.9.gz: ... text ...
./second_folder/31.11/access_log.9.gz: ... text ...
./second_folder/31.11/access_log.9.gz: ... text ...
:
```

### Question #2

How can I get all the records from all the files in all folders and save them individually depending on records I grab from first_folder, second_folder etc like `first.txt, second.txt`.

Output would look something like:

```
first.txt
./first_folder/11.11/access_log.9.gz: ... text ...
./first_folder/11.12/access_log.9.gz: ... text ...
:
second.txt
./second_folder/31.11/access_log.9.gz: ... text ...
./second_folder/31.15/access_log.9.gz: ... text ...
:
```

### Question #3

How can I get list of all the files that contain string `/Jan/2016`?

If I use this command, will it retrieve all the files:

```
$ find ~/Desktop/logs/ -type f | xargs zgrep -l "/Jan/2016"
```

Output:

```
Terminal
/home/name/Desktop/logs/first_folder/11.11/access_log.9.gz
/home/name/Desktop/logs/first_folder/11.12/access_log.8.gz
/home/name/Desktop/logs/second_folder/31.11/access_log.6.gz
:
```

### **Edit #2**

@waltinator-s code and @Zanna-s correction:

```
pushd ~/Desktop/logs
for dir in * ; do
    if [[ -d "$dir" ]] ; then
        outname="$dir.txt"
        find "$dir" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -l '/Jan/2016' >"$outname"
    fi
done
popd
```

will give me structure:

```
~/Desktop/logs
├── first_folder
|   └── first.txt
├── second_folder
|   └── second.txt
:
└── last_folder
    └── last.txt
```

where `first.txt-last.txt` will contain paths to specific files that contain string /Jan/2016.

```
first.txt
first_folder/11.11/access_log.9.gz
first_folder/11.11/access_log.8.gz
first_folder/11.12/access_log.9.gz
first_folder/11.12/access_log.8.gz
```

### **Question #4 (22.9.2016)**

I needed to modify `/Jan/2016` to certain period of time...for example `1/Nov/2014-31/Apr/2015` so in a code that @Zana provided instead of the `/Jan/2016` I used `/(Nov|Dec)/2014|/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr)/2015`.
Warning is thrown:

```
xargs: Warning: a NUL character occurred in the input.  It cannot be passed through in the argument list.  Did you mean to use the --null option?
```

All results are not returned in created files, althought all files are created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2. Have data that contains string in a separate text files depending on a folder (example: first folder - first.txt etc)

You could use a very simple loop to make a text file with the records for that directory inside the directory:

```
for d in ~/Desktop/logs/* ; do zgrep -E '/Jan/2016' "$d"/* >"$d"/out.txt ; done

Desktop/logs
├── first_folder
│   ├── access_log
│   ├── access_log.gz
│   └── out.txt
└── second_folder
    ├── access_log
    ├── access_log.gz
    └── out.txt
```

Using this slight adjustment to [waltinator's script](https://askubuntu.com/a/824540/527764):

```
for d in ~/Desktop/logs/* ; do
    if [[ -d "$d" ]] ; then
        outname="$d".txt
        find "$d" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -E '/Jan/2016' >"$outname"
    fi
done
```

will give this structure:

```
├── first_folder
│   ├── access_log
│   └── access_log.gz
├── first_folder.txt
├── second_folder
│   ├── access_log
│   └── access_log.gz
└── second_folder.txt
```

#### Notes

- `for d in ~/Desktop/logs/* ; do` loop over the contents of `~/Desktop/logs` and do something with them
- `if [[ -d "$d" ]]; then` do something only if `$d` is a directory
- `find "$d" -type f -print0` search inside directories `$d` for files and output them with the null separator so that we can use
- `xargs -0` construct a command with the output of the previous command as arguments, using the null character as separator (otherwise filenames with spaces break this approach)
- `zgrep` searches in zipped/compressed archives

Comment: First loop gives me: bash: ~Desktop/logs/*/out.txt: No such file or directory. Second one works like a charm! Thanks so much!

Comment: I have put this as a correct answer because this is what I was looking for. This gives an answer to the question #2!

Comment: @vayacondios2015 oops sorry I just missed a `/` from the loop - now fixed. Glad the second way worked how you wanted :)

Answer (score 4):

The modern way to use `find`, bearing in mind that you will eventually see a filename containing spaces, is with `-print0` and `xargs -0`:

```
# list all filenames containing '/Jan/2016'
find ~/Desktop/logs -type f -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -l '/Jan/2016'
# 1. Have all the data from all folders that contain that string under one text file
find ~/Desktop/logs -type f -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -l '/Jan/2016' >one.text.file
#
# 2. Have data that contains string in a separate text files depending on a folder (example: first folder - first.txt etc)
pushd ~/Desktop/logs
for dir in * ; do
    if [[ -d "$dir" ]] ; then
        outname="$dir.txt"
        find "~/Desktop/logs/$dir" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -l '/Jan/2016' >"$outname"
    fi
done
popd
```

Comment: Thanks for quick respond! Under 1. this gives me a list of folders that contain that string, but I would like to get actual data (all the logs).  Under 2. find: `~/Desktop/logs/first_folder': No such file or directory...it seems to me that it doesnt search for and under 11.11 etc folders.

Comment: I have edited my question regardless the issue under 1.

Comment: ah it's just a little slip there, instead of `find "~/Desktop/logs/"$dir"` it should be `find "$dir"` otherwise you get something like `/home/$USER/Desktop/logs/home/$USER/Desktop/logs/first_folder`, that's the only reason it didn't work @vayacondios2015 otherwise it's very nice